# Java simple regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to specify a regex that finds if there are any non letter non number chars in a String.

Basically I want it to accept `[a-z][A-Z][0-9]` in any order any combination..i.e `"2a4A44awA"` should be valid.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of:

```
[a-z][A-Z][0-9]
```

Match with:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

From the API:

```
Greedy quantifiers
X?  X, once or not at all
X*  X, zero or more times
X+  X, one or more times
X{n}    X, exactly n times
X{n,}   X, at least n times
X{n,m}  X, at least n but not more than m times
```

Comment: @Mixkat, I edited by answer to include the list of Greedy Quantifiers.

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = ".... ;

System.out.println(s.matches(".*[^a-zA-z0-9].*"));
```

returns true if illegal character is present.

**Edit:** But the first answer from jzd is better:

```
s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
```

Returns true if illegal character *not* present, ie the string is good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...the other answer is indeed simpler and works fine...well...thanks anyway